# A valid String cant be converted to JSONObject using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, json

I am reading some inforamtion from database as json object .
the database returns a well formated string ( as json object ) .
When i try to convert the string to jsonObject .. it returns null

here is the string from database :

```
{"items":[{"title":"Police","icon":"police","type":"normal","tel":"999"},{"title":"Ambulance","icon":"ambulance","type":"normal","tel":"976"},{"title":"Electricity","icon":"electricity","type":"normal","tel":"4848"},{"title":"Fire Station","icon":"fire","type":"normal","tel":"998"},{"title":"Airport Information 1","icon":"airport","type":"normal","tel":"0183447405"},{"title":"Airport Information 2","icon":"airport","type":"normal","tel":"0183780129"},{"title":"Water","icon":"water","type":"normal","tel":"3131"}],"success":1}
```

and here the response error from logcat :

```
12-18 20:24:44.529: W/System.err(25062): org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

as you can see it indicate that the string value is  empty  ... while the logcat shows me my string ....

Please note that this code was working very well  before ..

EDIT :
I tried the same code to read from different database . and it worked well
i guess its database error .

Comment: and how you converting `string` to `json object`?

Comment: JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject ( put my string here )